# Why is Android phone shutting down by itself?

Tags: samsung

Phone is Samsung Infuse 4G with Cyanogenmod 11 (Android 4.4). On a few recent occasions when I check it in the morning, I find that it's powered off. I start it up again, and it shows plenty of battery charge (75% or more). Is there a log or something that I can look at that would explain why it has shut down?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Solution:
Boot into CWM/TWRP Bootmenu (pressing "Volume up" Key and Power Button) while starting the phone -  and chose to clear "Dalvic Cache and Cache". Both will have **no** impact on your installed software or data. So it is quite safe to do.

After clearing reboot. The next restart will take a bit longer because these caches have to be rebuilt again. Solved my problem with random shutdowns.

Another possibility could be a dead battery. Especially if charging values change between full loading (100%) and after rebooting (90% or similar) ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's well known problem for Samsung phones and tablets:

Read carefully: http://androidforums.com/threads/randomly-turning-off.312084/

One of possible solution (cited from above post):

> I found another workaround, turning off sleep mode. Maybe there are
>   easier ways to do it, but i did it like this:
>
> (copied the instructions from another forum):
>
> - Download and install a free app Load Monitor.
> - Under its preferences check the following on...
> - Add Notification, Only notify high load, Auto start, and most importantly Wake Lock.
>
> The wake lock prevents the phone from going into sleep mode, now i'm
>   already 24 hours without shutdowns. I also set the update interval to
>   2 hours for the Load monitor, so it doesn't bug me often.
>
> The downside must be battery consumption, i assume that the sleep mode
>   does save up some juice. But at the moment i'd rather worry for the
>   battery than if the phone is on or not. :)
>
> Also, this problem is not limited to galaxy ace.. A little searching
>   with google revealed that there is even a class action lawsuit against
>   Samsung because of the same problem in Samsung S models.

Hope it Help